# Copy maven plugin from dependency with type pom

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I have project A which contains following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>vo.cjm.modules.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>basic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

In the pom of this dependency I have a plugin configured. However, this plugin is never executed when installing the project in the maven local repo. When moving the plugin to the pom of project A, it is executed.

In contrast to parent-child maven projects where plugins are inherited, here I find myself in the situation where only dependencies are inherited. Is it true that when using pom type, only dependencies are inherited and no plugins? If yes, how can I achieve to inherit plugins in maven without parent-child structure?

What I also tried, was using a parent project. In this project I define the child module, project A. In project A, I reference the parent project. When doing this, maven generates 'duplicate version' errors/warnings. The only way to eliminate this behavior is removing the version of project A. Now, projects A version is inherited from the parent project. I want to be able to manage the version of project A independently, so this is not an option.

I also tried to use a parent project, and define a module (project A) in there. However, this only works with the assumption you will always call maven on the parent project. Running maven on project A, will not inherit anything that is in the parent project.

Comment: I tried to answed your question, but it seems to me there may be another issue hiding behind. Why exactly don't you want to use the parent-child mechanism to inherit your plugins? Is it an issue like "If I define a plugin in the parent, all childs will inherit but I only want these few projects to" ?

Comment: The "childs" need their own versioning... I want to build my childs independently. Maven uses top-down approach, meaning you should always call the parent project. I don't want this approach... When adding the parent tag in the child module, maven complains you have duplicate versions... You should only use the one of the parent. Therefore, the child modules are dependent of the parent. I want the hierarchy reversed. =)

Comment: With Maven you can definitely version and build your childs independently. It may be a configuration issue if Maven complains about duplicate plugins versions. What is the exact issue and error message? If you have defined <plugins> in your parent and they are defined again in your child under <plugins>, you may be doing it wrong. If you want to inherit plugins in child you should use <pluginManagement> in your parent instead. But that is going out of the scope of your initial question, feel free to edit it to precise your issue, or it may be necessary to ask another one ;)

Comment: Try this basic maven setup (I am using 3.5): Just add in the parent a module. In the module reference the parent. In the module maven will generate warnings/errors about duplicate version numbering... Removing the parent reference in the module, will make the module work and have its own version, however nothing is inherited from the parent since the module itself is called :) Anyway I edited my question with more details. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the details, can you please provide the related pom.xml for both projects (your parent and child) which causes the error? (We'll get to the bottom of this!)

Comment: That's too complicated, I have more then 12 modules in different levels. If you just try a basic parent-child setup with maven and try to execute a plugin from the parent while running maven on the child, then you are my man ;) Shouldn't be difficult, right? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157487/discussion-between-pierre-b-and-fabi-yo).

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinguish the parent-child mechanism and the dependency mechanism.

- When specifying a parent for a pom (thus becoming a child pom), you will inherit every dependencies and plugins declared in `<dependencies>` and `<plugins>` elements, among other things
- When referencing dependencies in your pom with `<dependencies>`, you're telling Maven *"I need this artifact (jar, pom, other) in my project, and any other dependency this artifact is also depending on"*, but nothing related to plugins used by this dependency. Plugins are only used when building something with Maven. Once the artifact is built and available, there is no reason to include the plugins used by this artifact when it was built - imagine if for every dependency you used, you had tons of plugins you probably don't want suddenly added to your build !

> Is it true that when using pom type, only dependencies are inherited and no plugins?

Yes. When your dependency is of type `pom`, you're simply telling Maven to add all the dependencies of this pom to the current pom.

> If yes, how can I achieve to inherit plugins in maven without parent-child structure?

To the best of my knowledge, you can't. You have to use a parent pom if you want to inherit plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that dependencies are not part of the Maven project object model, so I'd say no.

We're using parent-child architectures to reuse plugins from parents.

We omit using them as Snapshots

```
parent with plugins +
                    |
                    + another parent with plugins +
                    |                             |
                    |                             + child artifact uses plugins
                    + child artifact uses plugins
```

and so on.

So parents can for example define a Java version, or they can contain profiles that child projects can use.

These are no reactor projects (no "modules"), just plain POM projects for this exact reason: To provide plugins, profiles and dependencyManagement for children.

Comment: you mean plugins are not a part of the maven project object model??

Comment: Sorry if my answer leads to confusion - they are part of the POM but not inheritable via dependencies, only via parent-POMs. The POM consists of a parent/child-architecture, but dependencies are just artifacts. Maybe this page can explain more details better than me: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html